# custom User model with token based authentication django

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-models, django-rest-framework

I am writing API for token-based authentication in django usign django rest framework. 
I have implemented it using default `User` model. But I need to add some more details in the User model.
After searching, I found `AbstractBaseUser`, `BaseUserMAnager`. I have implemented it too and written Serializer for it but getting errors.
There are too many different methods available online, now I am confused which one is the right way.

**models.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager

class MyUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, password):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('Enter email')

        user = self.model(
            email=email.normalize_email(email)
        )
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, password):
        user = self.create_user(email, password=password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user


class MyUser(AbstractBaseUser):

    email = models.EmailField(verbose_name='email address', max_length=255, unique=True, db_index=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'

    objects = MyUserManager()

    def get_short_name(self):
        return self.email

    def get_full_name(self):
        return self.email

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.email
```

**serializers.py**

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from bsa.models import MyUser
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model


class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    password = serializers.CharField(style={'input_type': 'password'})

class Meta:
    model = get_user_model()
    fields = ['email', 'password']

    def create(self, email, password):
        user = MyUser(email, password)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()
        return user
```

**views.py**

```
from bsa.serializers import UserSerializer
from rest_framework.decorators import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response

class Test(APIView):

    def post(self, request):
        serializer = UserSerializer( data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            #getting error here
            serializer.save()
            return Response({'detail': "POST Response"})
        return Response({'detail': "Response"})
```

**settings.py**

```
"""
Django settings for BSA2 project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 1.9.6.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/
"""

import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '1$x0gj(bx+ispf=f_a6-!syksl6qkier=6!@qh=m!w575!c!n+'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'bsa.MyUser'

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'bsa',
    'rest_framework',
]

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'BSA2.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')]
        ,
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'BSA2.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

**errors**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/envTut/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 149, in get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/root/envTut/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 147, in get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/root/envTut/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 58, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/root/envTut/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 68, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/root/envTut/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 466, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "/root/envTut/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 463, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/root/PycharmProjects/BSA2/bsa/views.py", line 20, in post
    serializer.save()
  File "/root/envTut/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 191, in save
    self.instance = self.create(validated_data)
TypeError: create() takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given)
```

if I remove self from create method in 'serializers.py'
error changes to

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/envTut/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 149, in get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/root/envTut/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 147, in get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/root/envTut/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 58, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/root/envTut/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 68, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/root/envTut/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 466, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "/root/envTut/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 463, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/root/PycharmProjects/BSA2/bsa/views.py", line 20, in post
    serializer.save()
  File "/root/envTut/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 191, in save
    self.instance = self.create(validated_data)
  File "/root/PycharmProjects/BSA2/bsa/serializers.py", line 16, in create
    user.save()
  File "/root/envTut/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py", line 74, in save
    super(AbstractBaseUser, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/root/envTut/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 708, in save
    force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
  File "/root/envTut/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 736, in save_base
    updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)
  File "/root/envTut/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 801, in _save_table
    forced_update)
  File "/root/envTut/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 831, in _do_update
    filtered = base_qs.filter(pk=pk_val)
  File "/root/envTut/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 790, in filter
    return self._filter_or_exclude(False, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/root/envTut/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 808, in _filter_or_exclude
    clone.query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))
  File "/root/envTut/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1243, in add_q
    clause, _ = self._add_q(q_object, self.used_aliases)
  File "/root/envTut/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1269, in _add_q
    allow_joins=allow_joins, split_subq=split_subq,
  File "/root/envTut/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1203, in build_filter
    condition = self.build_lookup(lookups, col, value)
  File "/root/envTut/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1099, in build_lookup
    return final_lookup(lhs, rhs)
  File "/root/envTut/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/lookups.py", line 19, in __init__
    self.rhs = self.get_prep_lookup()
  File "/root/envTut/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/lookups.py", line 57, in get_prep_lookup
    return self.lhs.output_field.get_prep_lookup(self.lookup_name, self.rhs)
  File "/root/envTut/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 744, in get_prep_lookup
    return self.get_prep_value(value)
  File "/root/envTut/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 976, in get_prep_value
    return int(value)
TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'UserSerializer'
```

I have written most of the code using django and drf documentation (some blogs too). Error is in `serializer.save()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first error that I see is that `def create(self, email, password)` should be receiving the arguments `self` and `validated_data`. For example:

```
def create(self, validated_data):
    """Create a new model instance"""
    return MyUser.objects.create(**validated_data)
```

Ideally, your serializer would contain all the fields need to create this user instance.